# Plant identification: Perilla or catnip

Tags: identification

I recently bought two packs of seeds of plants that I have never planted before: green perilla and catnip. These seeds were sowed in different containers. In what I thought was the catnip container, I have this plant.
[image]
Initially thinking it was catnip, I tried feeding it to my cat but he doesn't like it at all. And the smell, although strong, is different from the dried catnip smell. Just touching a single leaf will leave a strong scent on my fingers. So is this plant perilla or catnip? From online photos, catnip seems to have more triangular shaped leaves.

Comment: or maybe other Labiates/Laminaceae. I would wait more time (maybe to see the flowers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scent of dried catnip is somewhat different from the fresh plant leaves - the image you show does resemble Nepeta cataria, but I can't tell if the stems are square or not, it should have square shaped stems, though that may become more obvious as it grows. The seedling does not look like Perilla.

The other thing is, not all cats respond to catnip; it's around 66% of cats that like it, and most of them do not eat it - they smell it, roll in it, maybe lick it, occasionally nibble it, but it's not like cat grass (or ordinary grass) which they need to consume for health reasons. Catnip is sort of marijuana for cats, it gives them a high, but has no nutritional value for them. More information on cats and Nepeta here https://www.cat-world.com.au/all-about-catnip.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to have square stems. I guess it might be too early to tell. What should I expect in terms of flowers for catnip compared to green perilla?

Comment: Suggest you google Perillla green flowers and Nepeta cataria flowers, select Images and compare  them rather than me attaching links to images, but note, the main difference  between the plants is the serration at the edge of the  leaves  - Perilla has a much more jagged edge to the leaves than Nepeta. Both have square stems - if your plant doesn't, it won't be either of these

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like any perilla plant that I have seen. Perilla seedlings generally have a narrow and long trip at the end of the leaf. This one looks very rounded.